# When does File.ReadLines free resources

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

When working with files in C#, I am conditioned to think about freeing the associated resources.  Usually this is a using statement, unless its a one liner convenience method
like File.ReadAllLines, which will open and close the file for me.

.Net 4.0 has introduced the convenience method File.ReadLines.  This returns an IEnumerable and is billed as a more efficient way to process a file - it avoids storing the entire file in memory.  To do this I'm assuming there is some deferred execution logic in the enumerator.

Obviously since this method returns an IEnumerable, not and IDisposable, I can't go with my gut reaction of a using statement.

My questions is:
With this in mind, are there any gotchas on resource deallocation with this method?

Does calling this method mean that the release of the associated file locks is non-deterministic?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`IEnumerable` doesn't inherit from IDisposable because typically, the class that implements it only gives you the *promise* of being enumerable, it hasn't actually done anything yet that warrants disposal.

However, when you enumerate over it, you first retrieve an `IEnumerator` by calling the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` method, and typically, the underlying object you get back *does* implement `IDisposable`.

The way `foreach` is implemented is similar to this:

```
var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    // enumerate
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();
}
```

This way, if the object does indeed implement `IDisposable`, it will be disposed of. For `File.ReadLines`, the file isn't really opened until you start enumerating over it, so the object you get from `File.ReadLines` doesn't need disposing, but the enumerator you get, does.

As the comments indicate, `IEnumerator` does not inherit from `IDisposable`, even though many typical implementations does, whereas the generic `IEnumerator<T>` does inherit `IDisposable`.

Comment: Actually, IEnumerator doesn't implement IDisposable. But many *implementations* of IEnumerator do implement IDisposable, and the foreach loop, and the LINQ extension methods, all do an `as` cast to see if the enumerator implements IDisposable, and if so they call Dispose.

Comment: Correction: the non-generic IEnumerator doesn't implement IDisposable, but the generic one (`IEnumerator<T>`) does.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Gah, silly mistake, let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for Lasse's answer.

Particularly for `File.ReadLines` where the enumerator calls `.MoveNext()` the internal `TextReader` will be disposed of when it encounters an EOF, or if a fault occurs.

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    bool flag;
    try
    {
        switch (this.<>1__state)
        {
            case 0:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
                this.<>7__wrap2 = this.reader;
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                this.<line>5__1 = null;
                goto Label_005C;

            case 2:
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                goto Label_005C;

            default:
                goto Label_0078;
        }
    Label_003E:
        this.<>2__current = this.<line>5__1;
        this.<>1__state = 2;
        return true;
    Label_005C:
        if ((this.<line>5__1 = this.reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            goto Label_003E;
        }
        this.<>m__Finally3(); // Disposal at end of file.
    Label_0078:
        flag = false;
    }
    fault
    {
        this.System.IDisposable.Dispose(); // Disposal due to fault.
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update:

In .net 5 the `IEnumerable` it returns does implement `IDisposable` and you may need to call `Dispose` after casting. But it self disposes if you read until the end of the file.