# ASP.net C# : How to read 20 to 200 GB file line by line using File.ReadLines(fileName).GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are trying with below code.

```
 public static int SplitFile(string fileName, string tmpFolder, List<string> queue, int splitSize = 100000)
    {
        int chunk = 0;
        if (!Directory.Exists(tmpFolder))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpFolder);
        using (var lineIterator = File.ReadLines(fileName).GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool stillGoing = true;
            for (chunk = 0; stillGoing; chunk++)
            {
                stillGoing = WriteChunk(lineIterator, splitSize, chunk, tmpFolder, queue);
            }
        }
        return chunk;
    }

    private static bool WriteChunk(IEnumerator<string> lineIterator,
                                   int splitSize, int chunk, string tmpFolder, List<string> queue)
    {
        try
        {

            //int tmpChunkSize = 1000;
            //int tmpChunkInc = 0;
            string splitFile = Path.Combine(tmpFolder, "file" + chunk + ".txt");

            using (var writer = File.CreateText(splitFile))
            {
                queue.Add(splitFile);
                for (int i = 0; i < splitSize; i++)
                {
                    if (!lineIterator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(lineIterator.Current);

                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

It creates around 36 text files (around 800 MB), but starting throwing "Out of memory exception" in creation of 37th File at lineIterator.MoveNext().

While lineIterator.Current shows the value in debugger.

Comment: Have you tried with some arrays and removing items as you read/write them?

Comment: Here's an alternative using an iterator to read line by line that doesn't try to pull the whole file in memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line

Comment: Depending on how long the lines are, you'll probably run into large object heap fragmentation problems with this method

Comment: @Earlz That does seem most likely, but these would be some **very** long lines.

Comment: What are you reading that you have 20GB of text? Are these binary files you are using `ReadLines` on?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn if he is using the default `splitSize` value (**100000** ) it is not necessary to have very long lines to reach the LOH

Comment: @akfkmupiwu, what is the value of your `splitSize` variable? Have you tried with a lower value than 100000?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn depending on the file format, 8000 characters isn't "huge"

Comment: @Earlz 42500 (85000/2 bytes per char) is though.

Comment: @polkduran Splitsize is how many lines per file, but each line is read/written to the new stream one at a time, such that only one line is in ram at a time. That will only hit the LOH if individual lines are large enough

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn er. Yea, forgot. 85K not 8K. Although, it *maybe* actually only has to be 42500 characters, since characters are actually 2 bytes. I was assuming this would be a machine readable format though, I wouldn't say such a line size is unreasonable for a CSV file, for instance

Comment: Hi  polkduran , have tried with splitSize =20000  ,

Comment: Isn't this a candidate to use Task parallel library? And, if this is in asp.net, what would the user do while the splitting is on?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was thinking about an internal `buffer` used by the `StreamWriter` but the default buffer size is 1024 I think.

Comment: @akfkmupiwu, just to be sure the writer is not having a `buffer` size problem, can you try to make a `Flush` after the `WriteLine` call. I know this will affect performance but just for check if the `StreamWriter` isn't having problems.

Comment: All, I have tried this code on two separate machine of same config, it worked on another one. Then I published this on problematic system and it worked perfectly. Even till now I am not sure why this does not work with Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode, another info is, we are using MVC 3. I am logged in using Admin user on system.

Answer (score 0):

As It s a huge file you should read it `Seek` and `ReadBytes` methods of BinaryReader.

You can see a simple example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/seek). After you use the ReadBytes check for the last new lines and write the process file in certain amount of lines you read. Don t write every line you read and also don t keep all the data in the memory.

The rest is in your hands.

Maybe it is realted to that one [When does File.ReadLines free resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379267/when-does-file-readlines-free-resources)

> `IEnumerable` doesn't inherit from IDisposable because typically, the class that implements it only gives you the promise of being enumerable, it hasn't actually done anything yet that warrants disposal.

Comment: The whole point of [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) is specifically that it doesn't read the whole file into memory. There's something else going wrong here.

Comment: Based on your quote it seems you stopped reading the answer after that first paragraph.  I suggest you keep reading.  Also note that when the file handle is released is different from how long lines of text are stored in memory.  You can read a line of text and then release that memory before releasing the file handle.